# Save response to variable in Thunder Client

Tags: json, testing, postman, thunderclient

I want to save the response from two API calls but not sure how to do it in Thunder client, Postman is working fine.

```
var jsonDataResponse = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("tin", jsonDataResponse.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

One. https://generator.avris.it/api/DE/tin gives something like "21 348 504 760" and then in Postman I have this

[image: postman image 1]

But in Thunder, I have no idea how can I do that

[image: thunder try]

And I want to just the number without spaces

Two. I have this in Postman but no clue how made this in Thunder

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
positionstring=""+jsonData.positions;

pwdstring=positionstring.replace(new RegExp(",", "g"), "");
positionstring=positionstring.replace(new RegExp(",", "g"), "\",\"");

positionstring ="\[\""+positionstring+"\"\]";
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("positions", positionstring);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("pwd", pwdstring);
```

[image: postman image 2]

I tried the first one but only I get to save it to a tin variable with literally the function I want to replace(" ", "") when should be 21348504760

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it, here it is
Create a JavaScript file with the function like this

```
function positions() {  

// Parse the JSON text into an object
const jsonObject = tc.response.json;

// Create the positions array using the values from the JSON object
const twostring = jsonObject.positions.map(value => value);

// Create the pwd variable
const onestring= jsonObject.positions.map(Number).join('');

tc.setVar("onestring",onestring);   
tc.setVar("twostring",twostring);

}
module.exports = [positions]
```

Then in the request go to Tests tab, Post Request Script and select the function, in this case "positions".

(In order functions appear there, in collection options file should be listed in Script Files)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to convert JSON

The `responseBody` just string. So you just need to remove space from string of `responseBody`. And remove the Double Quote mark.
It will be a `string`, then convert into Number()

Then assign the environment variable into `tin`.

```
const tin_string = responseBody.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/"/g,'');

tin_number = Number(tin_string)

pm.environment.set("tin",tin_number)
```

If you want to debug the handling of your code in `Tests` tab, the console.log() is useful.

##### This is an example of debug.

```
console.log(responseBody)

const tin_string = responseBody.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/"/g,'');
console.log(tin_string)

tin_number = Number(tin_string)
console.log(tin_number)

pm.environment.set("tin", tin_number)
```

[image]

##### Assigned environment variable `tin`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will improve the postman but I need is to know how to do it in thunder client.

Comment: You are welcome, I happy to hear you got it. Can you accept me answer? you can click up arrow it will give a 15 points even if you are new user.(less than 15 points). The thunder client question you can post new question. it will be help from other expert people.